# Websocket max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded

Tags: scala, jboss, websocket, base64

In my scala application I use web sockets to get requests and send responses. When I try to pass a base64 string through web sockets following exception occurs

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.CorruptedFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
```

I tried the below solution to fix my issue

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx3084m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=2621440"
```

It works well in the Mac OS. But when I try the same solution in my windows(changed export to set) and Ubuntu machine it doesn't work. I get the same exception message. Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Default buffer size set for web socket is "65536". So you should increase the websocket buffer size in the application.conf file.

You can set the limit as given below.

```
play.websocket.buffer.limit=2621440
```

Answer (score 4):

Find a way to increase the maximum size of WebSocket frames. For example, in Java, `Session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(int)` and `Session.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create AsyncHttpClient manually. So I just set config

```
httpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
    .setMaxRequestRetry(0)
    .setWebSocketMaxBufferSize(1024000)
    .setWebSocketMaxFrameSize(1024000).build());
```

If you create this obj by Injector, then add

```
play.websocket.buffer.limit=2621440
```

into application.conf.